# Поиск выражения в текстовом файле

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re

 text = "text.txt"
 element_file = open(text, mode='r')
 look_text = element_file.read()
 textsearch = r""

 result = re.findall(textsearch, look_text)

 print(result)
```

text.txt

1:[Водоро́д (H, лат. hydrogenium)
    1-й химический элемент периодической системы.]

2:[Ге́лий — второй порядковый элемент периодической системы химических
    элементов Д. И. Менделеева, с атомным номером 2.]

Подскажите как правильно задать поиск чтобы вывело выражение в скобках за цифрой либо 1 или 2. 
Или как то можно это сделать проще, или текстовый файл записать как то другому?

github.com/maxim58r/Chemistry

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python как создать файл с пронумерованным списком для поиска в нем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/950284/python-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Comment: Не нужно повторно задавать одни и те же вопросы .

Comment: Я удалил тот вопрос чтобы не было повтора. Можете помочь с этим вопросом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так нужно?

```
import re

look_text = '1:[Водоро́д (H, лат. hydrogenium) 1-й химический элемент периодической системы.]\n2:[Ге́лий — второй порядковый элемент периодической системы химических элементов Д. И. Менделеева, с атомным номером 2.]'
num = 1
textsearch = r"{}:\[(.+)\]".format(num)

result = re.findall(textsearch, look_text)

print(result)
```

Comment: Да. Но как сделать чтобы он его и текстового файла забирал и выводил.  look_text = "text.txt"  если я ссылку на файл делаю то он возвращает []. Почему так?

Comment: Такого не может быть, загрузи образец файла на pastebin.com

Comment: Разобрался. В файле не правильно текст был составлен. Спасибо заработало.

Comment: https://github.com/maxim58r/Chemistry [Вот что в итоге получилось][1] . Только текст в всплывающем окне не умещается. Как нужно его написать чтобы он весь появлялся.